# VBA - Format date for ComboBox does not work

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

My code to format combobox is below, but it does not work.  Simply want to format date as d-mmm-yy.  I tried Application.EnableEvents True, etc... nothing is working.  Please help?

```
    UserForm9.ComboBox10.Value = Format(UserForm9.ComboBox10.Value, "d-mmm-yyyy")
    UserForm9.ComboBox11.Value = Format(UserForm9.ComboBox11.Value, "d-mmm-yyyy")

    UserForm9.ComboBox10.Value = ws.Cells(foundCell_Database.Row, 21).Value
    UserForm9.ComboBox11.Value = ws.Cells(foundCell_Database.Row, 22).Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Done, I got it to work now... The format code must go "after" the data pull.  (Originally, I had the format code "before", but should be "after".)  Anyways, close this ticket. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Actually you can "close" it by marking your answer as a solution.